# How to reverse escape output

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-maps

I have a list of strings in a database that are already HTML-escaped.  For example, I have `Kind of Business&trade;`.

This works well for printing right to an HTML document with `raw` or `html_safe`, unfortunately, when I use the string in a map marker, the Google Maps API doesn't need escaped strings to function as an HTML document does.

Is there a way in Rails to render the escaped content and then pass it to Google Maps?

---

Edit:  Now using:

```
<%=raw HTMLEntities.new.decode(str) %>
```

Comment: I'd probably store the strings without HTML encoding in the database for indexing and search-ability reasons.

Comment: Yes, I agree this is a better method.  Unfortunately what is done cannot easily be undone, most times

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this gem:

http://github.com/threedaymonk/htmlentities

For decoding use:

```
HTMLEntities.new.decode "Business&trade;"
=> "Business™"
```

And for encoding:

```
HTMLEntities.new.encode "Business™"
=> "Business&trade;"
```

Comment: Is this a gem?  I'm getting an uninitialized constant problem.  Please see edit

Comment: Nope, it should be standard Rails functionality. Which version of Rails are you using?

Comment: Rails doesn't have a `HTMLEntities` class, but there's https://github.com/threedaymonk/htmlentities

Comment: I mean it should be standard Ruby functionality. http://htmlentities.rubyforge.org/

Comment: I'm using ruby 1.9 and rails 3

Comment: @Stefan is right. You could use the gem he mentions. I'll update my answer. Didn't see I had it in my gemfile.. -.-

Answer (score 1):

```
CGI.unescapeHTML("test &quot;unescaping&quot; &lt;characters&gt;")
```

Answer (score 0):

Without external gem:

```
CGI.escape 'https://google.com' # returns 'https%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com'
```

Reverse will be easy to guess:

```
CGI.unescape 'https%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com' # returns 'https://google.com'
```

Note CGI.unescapeHTML seems to work only for HTML tags, not for simple strings.